# How do i link all this images with an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i link all this images to an array, so as this links can work when i click each image slide

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
var bgImageArray = ["banner1.jpg", "banner2.jpg", "banner3.jpg"], 
var links = ['http://google.com', 'http://hotmail.com', 'http://yahoo.com', 'http://kimjoyfox.com'],
base = window.location.origin + "/wp-content/themes/fbnquest/img/home/",
secs = 4;
bgImageArray.forEach(function(img){
    new Image().src = base + img; 
    // caches images, avoiding white flash between background replacements

});
```

Comment: `links[indexOfLinkClicked]` redirect to this

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: How is the link clinked? Where are you displaying the links?

Comment: as per Banner clicked i want them to redirect to one of the links

Comment: send the code of your banner and its click event

Comment: okay will do now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand your problem is the following :

For each time you click on one of each of the images, you want to redirect the user to one of the URLs, changing the URL each time the user click on the image.

Is it what you want ? If not, please can you precise your problem

[EDIT]

So yes, 
Here is my way of solving your problem, If you don't matter, I won't give you code, obviously, you do this for training, let's do it :

- Create an eventListener on click that will trigger a function called ChangeImageUrl (for example) and assign that eventListener to all the img elements
- Then create a function that will detect the current URL of the image clicked, using imgElement.src ( i advice you to devide the src string using split or equivalent, that way you can directly access by index the current url )
- Once you have the URL Use yourUrlArray.indexOf(currentImageSrcUrl), to catch the index of the current URL in your array, store it and increment it ( bonus if the increment value is upper than the URL array length, set it to 0 )
- access the new src using yourUrlArray[newindex]
- assign current img element the new src that we juste have extracted

Tell me if this answer is good for you, I hope it will

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to understand what do you really want and I did something that I hope help you.

Inside of the loop  you can do in this way below.

```
var i = new Image();
i.src = base + img;
```

Comment: i just want when i clicked on a banner should redirect to One of the links stated Google and rest